# Query Update Type

Tags: marketing-cloud, query

I am have a very basic simple query to update data extension. Using "UPdate type" as Update.

here is the query;

```
SELECT * FROM Account_Salesforce
```

It's updating the data extension but if source data have deleted any record then I can still see deleted record in destination data extension.

Is there any method query can remove record if record is deleted from source data extension?

Comment: Marketing Cloud uses SQL, not SOQL. Can't properly tag from the mobile app.

Answer (score 1):

There's no deleting with a Query Activity, unless you choose *Overwrite* as the update type.

Also, do not use `select *` in your queries. SFMC caches the column names.  If you add or remove a column from the DE, the select will not include it.